# FontAwesome `fa-spin` Edge browser glitch

Tags: css, overlay, font-awesome, microsoft-edge

I'm working a little dashboard app for one of our internal systems, and opted to add a full-screen overlay when something is loading. It all works fine in Chrome, but on Edge I get something to this effect...

[image: Loader Quirk]

As far as I can tell its caused by having the `fa-spin` class on my main loading indicator as well as the overlay being transparent. I've removed `fa-spin`, Edge still has a few weird side effects (that I can live with), but it exacerbated by having the spin effect active.

**Questions:**

Has anyone encountered this before as my google attempts are returning seemingly futile results. Is there even a fix / work around for this, or is it just Edge being Edge...

Even though I'd love to opt and say to our users to not use Edge / IE, I'd feel like I'm giving up which isn't an option :P

**HTML structure** *(More or less)*

```
<div class="container-fluid" ng-class="{ 'overlay' :  vm.isLoading }">
    <div ng-if="vm.isLoading">
        <div class="overlay-modal">
            <p><i class="fa fa-gear fa-spin"></i>
            </p>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-7 main">
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-12 container-fluid" ng-class="{ 'blur' :  vm.isLoading }">
                        ...
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-5">
        ...
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Are you using toggle class?

Comment: @norcaljohnny nope, loading is done by toggling the loader using `ng-if` (in Angular)

Comment: `fa-spin` does nothing for me in Edge, not just for my own website but other websites too

Comment: @GlassCannon sorry to hear that man. It def worked for me, on this and other projects. Also this question is 6 years old already, and I haven't used FontAwesome in a while. My best guess is perhaps the api/css classes changed? Short of that, it's potentially something unique to your environment?
To test, does this appear like its spinning for you? https://fontawesome.com/v6/docs/web/style/animate#spin-utilities

Comment: @RohanBüchner I managed to get it fixed but it was the strangest thing, `fa-spin` in 4.7.0 works but not 6.0.1, custom CSS animation works but not on that website, cause was a `Windows` OS setting, I had to turn off something then turn it back on again in `Adjust the appearance and performance of Windows`

Answer (score 0):

I've just tried on my dashboard application using fa-spin and I can assure you that it didn't caused my issues. I've tried fontawesome both from cdn and embedded in my static files. Most probably that weird effect is caused by a number of overlapping CSS/JS styles/class toggling. I hope this answers your question.

Comment: Would you be able to provide a sample perhaps? So I can compare against my current markup and css?